# Getter Setter Returns Nothing-Java

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

My first list1 and my list show the right values but the second list1 shows nothing:

```
public class IcsList {
ArrayList<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> list(ArrayList list){
     this.list1= list;
    Log.i("list1", "" + list1);
    Log.i("list", "" + list);
    setList();
     return list;
}
public ArrayList setList(){
    Log.i("list1", "" + list1);
    return list1;
   }
```

Here is my logcat:

```
04-27 21:45:10.094  31548-31597/com.parse.starter I/list﹕ [B Soccer @ Liberty, Apr 28 2015 5:30 PM, KGHS Athletics, G Soccer v Liberty (home), Apr 28 2015 5:30 PM, KGHS Athletics
04-27 21:45:10.133  31548-31597/com.parse.starter I/list1﹕ [B Soccer @ Liberty, Apr 28 2015 5:30 PM, KGHS Athletics, G Soccer v Liberty (home), Apr 28 2015 5:30 PM, KGHS Athletics
 04-27 21:45:10.133  31548-31548/com.parse.starter I/list1﹕ []
```

By the way I'm trying to use this arraylist in another class by adding the string values to an array list in that class. Could setList() be making it empty? And should I instead say "return this.list1". By the way there is an arraylist in another class and I am calling list.(ArrayList). The getter is going to be called in another class to retrieve this arraylist. This class is like a relay between the two.

In my first class where I set the arrayList in the IcsList:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new     ArrayList();
 //add to arrayList
 IcsList list = new IcsList();
 list.list(arrayList);
```

Class that retrieved from IcsList:

```
  ArrayList<String> arrayList = new     ArrayList();

 IcsList list = new IcsList();
arrayList=  list.setList();
```

Comment: What do you think String.valueOf(ArrayList x) does?

Comment: I think you have miss concept of getters and setters methods.

Comment: Well, this is similar to how a lot of toturials showed how to do this

Comment: So what your saying is it isn't possible to  get the value of list1 with this class?

Comment: Have you rearranged the log cat you showed? It's not in the order that would be produced if `list()` were called. Or can you show what methods were called and in what order to produce the log you showed?

Comment: Good point, no I didnt rearrange them.

Comment: I started answering this question and came to the same conclusion as in the first answer. You must have called something else other than what you've described, because calling `list` should produce three nearly identical log lines. You need to show exactly what method calls you're making that lead to the log you're showing.

Comment: Your "setter" (setList) is actually a getter. Your "getter" ... is...well, whatever it is, it's not a getter. You put a value in, and you return the same value... that's not a getter in the usual sense. You are claiming this is as it is done in "a lot" of tutorials ... I beg to differ. Read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in this predicament my getter-setter:

```
public class IcsList {
static ArrayList<String> list1;
public IcsList(){
    list1 =new ArrayList<String>();}


public static ArrayList<String> getList1(){
return list1;
} }
```

Where I add to the ArrayList in the IcsList class:

```
IcsList icsList= new IcsList();
ArrayList<String> arrayList= icsList.getList1();
arrayList.add(event);
arrayList.add(honey);
arrayList.add(happy);
```

Where I retrieve the ArrayList to use in another class:

```
ArrayList<String> list2= new ArrayList();
list2= IcsList.getList1();
```

I would describe this as a "relay system."

Answer (score 2):

Taylor: based on your last answer for yourself - you have some misunderstandings:

Class IcsList has static list1. It means that all instances share the same ONE list1 ArrayList. So, whoever and whenever uses your class - it is always one the same list1 object.

Even more strange - you initialize this list1 in constructor of the IcsList. Which means list1 is null until you create at least one instance of IcsList. Which is impractical and confusing. Even worse - every new IcsList() will update this list1 with new fresh and empty ArrayList. Which is weird too.

Your last code shows that you create list2 and then immediately override it list1 reference. This has no sense either.

I assume what you want is this:

```
public class IcsList {
private ArrayList<String> list1;
   public IcsList(){
      list1 =new ArrayList<String>();
   }


   public static ArrayList<String> getList1(){
      return list1;
   } 
}
```

then second one is right (assuming honey is "honey") and third one would be

```
ArrayList<String> list2= = icsList.getList1(); // this is list1 from existing object icsList
if (list2.contains(honey)) System.out.println("honey is here");
if (icsList.getList1().contains(honey)) System.out.println("honey is still here");
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide full comprehensive code. It looks like you call setList() from another place just after you had instantiated your object IcsList.

I see it because if you run your code as it is (assuming adding the rest to be at least compile) then all 3 lines of logcat would be identical. However they all are different, even first and second.

My suggestion is to add specific details details to each output. At least method name or stack trace and you will see the difference - who is calling and when - and there would be no confusion.

Comment: You can add stack trace directly to your logcat like this: Log.i("list1", "" + list1, new Throwable().fillInStackTrace());